# Proper Mahout CVB max iteration count

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning, mahout, lda

When using the mahout cvb from the command line. what is the best way to determine to determine the iteration count number?

-x is the argument to set it. 
The default appears to be 4 (from other readings), and the more iterations set, the accurate the result. But how does one know the proper size to set it?

Answer (score 0):

You got a try out different values of 'x' and evaluate the topical classification for each case.  I would start with 4 and 10 and then run thru a binary search.